# How to get pinned videos through Vimeo API?

Tags: vimeo-api

I'm using Vimeo API to get a list of all videos in my own profile using `https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos`. What I get in return is a list of videos that are not in the same order that in the profile, because there are some videos that are pinned, i.e. they appear first.
Is there a way ti get the pinned videos only? Or order them first?

I already tried this two ways:

`https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?filter=featured&access_token=<token_id>
 https://api.vimeo.com/users/<user_id>/videos/?filter=featured&access_token=<token_id>`

Answer (score 0):

`GET https://api.vimeo.com/users/{user_id}/videos` with `filter` param set to `featured` should be what you're looking for.

You can view more info about that request [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos).

Comment: Didn't work. If I use the `&filter=featured` nothing changes.

Comment: I just asked the team that manages the API and it sounds like it _should_ be working in all versions. "Featured should be in all versions now. Let me double check...Yes, the `featured` filter on `/me/videos` and `/users/<id>/videos` is not gated by version anymore." Could you possibly edit your question and add in the code that you're making the request with?

Comment: @ftpaul Try providing your access token in the request body instead of the request uri. While the access_token parameter is supported, it's best practice to only provide the token in the body per documentation: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#making-requests